# What does the 'clearBufferedCommand() method do in Node.js REPL

Tags: node.js

What is the use of the 'clearBufferedCommand()' method in Node.js?

This code is from Node.js specification but I cannot see any use of this method.

```
const repl = require('repl');

const replServer = repl.start({ prompt: '> ' });
replServer.defineCommand('sayhello', {
    help: 'Say hello',
    action(name) {
        this.clearBufferedCommand();
        console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
        this.displayPrompt();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_replserver_clearbufferedcommand):

> The `replServer.clearBufferedCommand()` method clears any command that
>   has been buffered but not yet executed. This method is primarily
>   intended to be called from within the action function for commands
>   registered using the [`replServer.defineCommand()`](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_replserver_definecommand_keyword_cmd) method.